# Performing DNS Queries via Javascript from Chrome App

Tags: dns, google-chrome-extensions

Goal: Create a Chrome app/extension to determine value of DNS requests in local value (i.e., determine what A and CName records a local machine or its delegated resolver is returning when Chrome issues a DNS request). For example, the Chrome app would take as input "www.google.com" and return the IP of the A record.

I have thus far tried two different approaches:

(1) http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.htm
This is very close. I am able to simulate a UDP connection on port 53. The only problem is that I don't know what the hostname is for the DNS resolver.

(2) https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html
This is not that close to providing what I need.

Comment: A few leads after much searching: (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691119/chrome-packaged-app-udp-sockets-not-working (2) mDNS browser extension https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/mdns-browser

Comment: There is a DNS client library for Javascript at DNS-JS.com that might help?